# С++ checking thread stack size with crashing

Tags: c++, linux, windows, stack-overflow, stack-size

I have a crossplatform multithread program (Windows/Linux) that works fine on Linux and crashes on Windows. Searching in the internet gives me an idea, that this is because of stackoverflow: Linux and Windows thread stack sizes may differ. So how can I check each thread (not only the main one) stack size? Write to stack until the program crashes (need to work both on windows and linux)? And how get the size then?

Comment: Run your program under a debugger and the offending thread will make itself known instantly.

Comment: Unfprtunately, there is nothing in the C++ standard that implements a standard way to do this. There might be operating system-specific features that will give you this information. But the right solution is to use appropriate, optimal algorithms that minimize stack usage.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentthreadstacklimits

Comment: ***that works fine on Linux and crashes on Windows.*** Remember that the default stack size is 1MB on msvc. I believe it's 8MB on linux usually. That could easily cause the problem if you developed on linux.

Comment: Why are you using so much stack?  Is that something you can address?  If so, that might be the best approach - then the problem might go away on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution of knowing a thread stack size on both platforms is a simple testing program: create thread, write to stack recursively until the program crashes. And yes, it's 1MB on Windows and 8 MB on Linux ARM.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

#if __linux__
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
#ifdef WINDOWS
#include <windows.h>
#endif

void mySleep(int sleepMs)
{
#if __linux__
    usleep(sleepMs * 1000); 
#endif
#ifdef WINDOWS
    Sleep(sleepMs);
#endif
}

int counter {0};

void thread_func()
{
    counter++;
    std::cout << "func recursive step: " << counter << std::endl;
    size_t sz = sizeof(unsigned long long);
    std::cout << "size of ulonglong: " << sz << std::endl;
    for(int i=0; i< 1000000; i++)
    {   
        unsigned long long crush_array[5000]; //1 element = 8 byte (on windows)
        for (auto &ar : crush_array)
            ar = 18446744073709551614;
        
        std::cout << "write " << sz*5000 <<"B array to stack" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "thread stack size is less then " << (float)(sz*5000*counter)/(1024*1024) << " MB"<< std::endl << std::endl;
        thread_func();
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    std::thread thread_obj = std::thread(thread_func);
    thread_obj.detach();
    mySleep(50000);
    system("pause");
}
```

Result on Windows

[image]

Result on Linux ARM

[image]